# Show PHP echo results when called by JSON rpc?

Tags: php, json

I am using JSON to run some PHP functions and 1 of them is not working and is returning null. How can i return a php output e.g. an echo of variable/array from the php function and view in firebug/on screen? I'm sure i have done this before but cant remember how!?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo json_encode(array("hello" => "world"))
```

Will output a JSON encoded array, you can then access this script via an Ajax call, Firebug can view this and you can debug from there?

Comment: just to clarify in javascript you'd access it doing $('#example').val(hello.world); In jquery...

Answer (score 0):

I used this to pass POST and GET arrays into json, so:

```
$var = <?php json_encode($_POST); ?>
```

So if i have $_POST['test'] = 'what'

to access it i do $var.test which is equal to 'what'